# SSRS using a cube - parameter defaults messing things up

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2012

I created a report in SSRS (2010) using a SSAS cube (which is new to me). I added parameters using the "Query parameters" option in Query Designer.

The problem is, it makes me select a default parameter when it really isn't applicable to my report. The OK button is grayed out until I pick a default param.

Further, I went into the parameter it created (under Report Data->Parameters) and made it not need a default.  My report didn't work properly. It uses all the choices from that parameter even though I selected 1 and hit "View Report".

Comment: If your report depends on a parameters it must have a default value or you have to select a value manually. Explain how you set the Parameter in the designer, note you if you have a parameter called `Year` in the report you have to put `@Year` in the designer and set a default value.

Comment: But when I use a relational DB query, I don't need to have a default param.

Comment: Yes, when you query a relational DB you just need to put `@Parameter` in your query, it is not necessary to add a parameter in the designer, In MDX you have to add the parameter in the query designer and define there a default value, that default value will not be used, the actual default value used will be that you set in your SSRS parameter.